# Render normalize.css + emotion styles with Next.js

Tags: css-modules, next.js, emotion, server-side-rendering

I'm trying to add Normalize.css as global and use emotion for my CSS Modules.

First my `.babelrc`

```
{
  "presets": [
    ["env", {
      "modules": false,
      "useBuiltIns": true
    }],
    "next/babel"
  ],
  "plugins": [
    "syntax-dynamic-import",
    "transform-runtime",
    "transform-decorators-legacy",
    "transform-class-properties",
    "transform-object-rest-spread",
    "es6-promise",
    ["module-resolver", {
      "root": ["./src"],
      "alias": {
        "styles": "./styles",
        "assets": "./assets",
      },
      "cwd": "babelrc"
    }],
    ["inline-import", { "extensions": [".css"] } ],
    ["emotion", { "inline": true }]
  ]
}
```

### Adding Normalize.css

In my `_document.js` I added the normalize

```
import Document, { Head, Main, NextScript } from 'next/document';
import normalize from 'normalize.css/normalize.css';
import { extractCritical } from 'emotion-server';

export default class MyDocument extends Document {
  static getInitialProps({ renderPage }) {
    const page = renderPage();
    const styles = extractCritical(page.html);
    return { ...page, ...styles };
  }

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    const { __NEXT_DATA__, ids } = props;
    if (ids) {
      __NEXT_DATA__.ids = ids;
    }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <html>
        <Head>
          <title>SSR</title>
          <style jsx global>{normalize}</style>
          <style dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: this.props.css }} />
        </Head>
        <body>
          <Main />
          <NextScript />
        </body>
      </html>
    );
  }
}
```

Same as [shown here](https://github.com/zeit/next.js/tree/canary/examples/with-global-stylesheet-simple)

### Addin my css modules with Emotion

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Breadcrumb from 'components/Breadcrumb';
import Link from 'next/link';
import styled, { hydrate, keyframes, css, injectGlobal } from 'react-emotion';

// Adds server generated styles to emotion cache.
// '__NEXT_DATA__.ids' is set in '_document.js'
if (typeof window !== 'undefined') {
  hydrate(window.__NEXT_DATA__.ids);
}


  const basicStyles = css`
    background-color: white;
    color: cornflowerblue;
    margin: 3rem 0;
    padding: 1rem 0.5rem;
  `

  const Basic = styled.div`
    ${basicStyles};
  `

export default class extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Basic>
        <p>Basic style rendered by emotion</p>
      </Basic>);
  }
}
```

Same as [shown here](https://github.com/zeit/next.js/tree/canary/examples/with-emotion)

### Problem

> Error: StyleSheet: `insertRule` accepts only strings.
>       at invariant (/home/riderman/WebstormProjects/tmp/node_modules/styled-jsx/dist/lib/stylesheet.js:274:11)
>       at StyleSheet.insertRule (/home/riderman/WebstormProjects/tmp/node_modules/styled-jsx/dist/lib/stylesheet.js:125:7)
>       at /home/riderman/WebstormProjects/tmp/node_modules/styled-jsx/dist/stylesheet-registry.js:88:29
>       at Array.map (native)
>       at StyleSheetRegistry.add (/home/riderman/WebstormProjects/tmp/node_modules/styled-jsx/dist/stylesheet-registry.js:87:27)
>       at JSXStyle.componentWillMount (/home/riderman/WebstormProjects/tmp/node_modules/styled-jsx/dist/style.js:58:26)
>       at resolve (/home/riderman/WebstormProjects/tmp/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.node.development.js:2616:12)
>       at ReactDOMServerRenderer.render (/home/riderman/WebstormProjects/tmp/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.node.development.js:2746:22)
>       at ReactDOMServerRenderer.read (/home/riderman/WebstormProjects/tmp/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.node.development.js:2722:19)
>       at renderToStaticMarkup (/home/riderman/WebstormProjects/tmp/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.node.development.js:2991:25)

### Added

Check source code [here](https://gitlab.com/problems/test-emotion-plus-global-nextjs)

https://gitlab.com/problems/test-emotion-plus-global-nextjs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like there's an issue for this over on Zeit's styled-jsx page: https://github.com/zeit/styled-jsx/issues/298

According to this issue it is either external styles or that you need to add the `css` tag to your template literals.

Looking at your code you are using the `css` tag and don't see any externals styles that would be causing this.  If you don't get a definite answer I'd say to follow up on issue 298 with Zeit.  HTH, cheers!

### Edit

Get rid of the jsx styles in there and just add normalize to your global template string:

```
injectGlobal`
    ${normalize}
    html, body {
      padding: 3rem 1rem;
      margin: 0;
      background: papayawhip;
      min-height: 100%;
      font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
      font-size: 24px;
    }
  `;
```

Comment: I'm not using `style-jsx`. It is not related.

Comment: You are using `<style jsx global>`, so it looks like you are trying to.  

An easy fix is to just get rid of your `<style jsx global>...` and use a template string to inject normalize, I'll update my answer with that example.

Answer (score 1):

I have an additional answer to this that works well in `TypeScript` and `NextJS 9`.  It also keeps your import directly based on your node_modules.

`Import raw-loader` for the module:

```
yarn add raw-loader
```

In a `global.d.ts`, define a hook for raw-loader

```
declare module '!!raw-loader!*' {
  const contents: string;
  export = contents;
}
```

In a component called Meta I have inside my `_document.tsx` ( `_app.tsx` would be fine too, but `_document` ensures SSR), I have this

```
import normalizeCss from '!!raw-loader!normalize.css';

const Meta = () => (
  <div>
    <Global
      styles={css`
        ${normalizeCss}
        body {
          // ...
        }
      `}
     ></Global>
  </div>
);

export default Meta;
```

Comment: Thks! Works to me. Next.js 12.2.5